# Looking for high accuracy lidar sensor on short range

Tags: sensors, lidar

Can someone suggest me where I can find high accuracy, high resolution lidar sensors? The sensor should have a resolution of 1mm. The accuracy should be very high ~1mm. The sensors can be short range from 1m - 4m. FOV should be >= 60°. Framerate should be > 60Hz.
Google doesn't give me any results.
I need it for high accuracy 3D reconstruction.

Comment: shopping questions are off topic here

Answer (score 1):

What about [laser profile sensors](https://www.google.com/search?q=laser+profile+sensor)?

Other relevant search terms are [3D machine vision](https://www.google.com/search?q=3D+machine+vision) and [3D machine vision laser](https://www.google.com/search?q=3D+machine+vision+laser).

Comment: I think laser profile sensors are usable for VERY short range scanning right? I want to scan objects of 1m size.

Comment: Not necessarily. E.g. this is one of the first search results from the laser profile sensors link I provided: [Z-Trak LP1 Laser Profiler](https://www.teledynedalsa.com/en/products/imaging/3d-sensors/z-trak-lp1-laser-profiler).
If you click on it you will read "Z-Trak models handle object widths from 8.5 mm to 1520 mm and height range of 10 mm to 1000 mm". But you need to click.